# android - reverse the order of an array

Tags: android, arrays, reverse

I have an array of objects.

Is it possible to make a new array that is a copy of this array, but in reverse order?
I was looking for something like this.

```
// my array
ArrayList<Element> mElements = new ArrayList<Element>();
// new array
ArrayList<Element> tempElements = mElements;

tempElements.reverse(); // something to reverse the order of the array
```

Answer (score 232, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

```
ArrayList<Element> tempElements = new ArrayList<Element>(mElements);
Collections.reverse(tempElements);
```

Comment: Yikes, thanks Ted. Looks like I have some java.util.* reading to do.

Answer (score 3):

**Kotlin**

```
val reverseList: List<Int> = yourActualList.reversed();
```

[Reference](https://www.techiedelight.com/reverse-copy-list-kotlin/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach without implementing anything.

```
                ArrayList<YourObject> oldlist = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
                ArrayList<YourObject> newList = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
                int size = oldlist.size()-1;

                for(int i=size;i>=0;i--){
                    newList.add(oldlist.get(i));
                }
```

Comment: An improvement would be to create `newList` with an initial capacity at least equal to the size of `oldList`. That would avoid internal memory reallocations as elements are added in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

For Android on Kotlin, this can be done with Anko's [`forEachReversedByIndex{}`](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/anko/library/static/commons/src/collections/Collections.kt#L49-L55) lambda operation, like this:

```java
val tempElements = ArrayList<Element>(mElements.size)
mElements.forEachReversedByIndex{tempElements.add(it)}
```

Comment: An improvement would be to create `tempElements` with an initial capacity at least equal to the size of `mElements`. That would avoid internal memory reallocations as elements are added in the second line.

Comment: @TedHopp thanks for the suggestion, will see to incorporate it to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I reversed the Profile from ascending to descending order by

In kotlin

```
 // A comparator to compare points of Profile 
class ProfileComparator {
    companion object : Comparator<Profile?> {
        override fun compare(o1: Profile?, o2: Profile?): Int {
            if (o1 == null || o2 == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return o2.points.compareTo(o1.points)
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
var profilesList = profiles.sortedWith(ProfileComparator)
```