# Java - a single generic method to reverse ArrayList or List of objects

Tags: java, android, arrays, reverse, generic-programming

I have seen that there is a very convenient way to reverse `ArrayList` [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5412542/461212) using `Collections.reverse()` method, but I need to achieve such a reverse operation for several types of primitive objects, like at least `ArrayList` and `List` of my custom objects. So `Collections` can't save my life for an extended usage of a single method.

So far I managed to get stg working (See code below) but I have to write it twice: once for ArrayList and once for List. I named them both the same so usage is very convenient, but some .. optimization would be even more convenient :-).

How to commonalize these 2 methods into a single (real) generic one ?

Thx

---

```
/**
 * Generic Reverse Method for ARRAYLIST using Iterator
 * @param ArrayList<Obj_item> notReversed
 * @return ArrayList<Obj_item> reversed
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <Obj_item> ArrayList<Obj_item> GenReverseArrayByIterator(ArrayList<Obj_item> mylist) {
                       // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ how to make this generic ?
    // Instanciate
    ArrayList<Obj_item> tmp = new ArrayList<Obj_item>();
    ArrayList<Obj_item> reversed = new ArrayList<Obj_item>();

    // Copy original list
    tmp = mylist;

    // Generate an iterator, starting right after the last element.
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    ListIterator myIterator = tmp.listIterator(tmp.size());

    // Iterate in reverse direction
    while (myIterator .hasPrevious()) {
        reversed.add((Obj_item) myIterator.previous());
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

Comment: Your method already *is* generic - and it's still not clear why you can't use `Collections.reverse()`. Also, your use of the word "primitive" sounds wrong to me...

Comment: Sorry for the wrong terminology usage, as for me, "primitive"  reads as "primitive objects" like ArrayList, opposit to custom objects. The point is that I have to write this method twice: once for ArrayList and once for List. I would like to write a single method if possible.

Comment: You mean library classes - there's no such thing as a primitive object!

Comment: @hornetbzz: No, you really don't - because of Paul's answer. It's also worth becoming aware of Java terminology and using it consistently - the primitive types are `int`, `short`, `boolean` etc.

Comment: I tried to use Collections but that did not do the trick as I have several "library classes" to get sorted or reversed. Depending on the custom object they content, it works or not but could not get it fixed after hours, therefore I wrote those 2 generic methods, which work for all my needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Collections.reverse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29) takes a `List<?>`. `ArrayList` implements `List` - you can use that method on an `ArrayList` or any `List` implementation. What you're doing seems entirely unnecessary, unless I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thx. No no, you have perfectly well understood the question. Your answer makes thgs more cristal clear for me as a noob. Thx again to you both guys.

Comment: Make sure your custom object implements Compareable for this to work correctly.

Comment: @Bill That shouldn't matter as the objects aren't being sorted - just reversed in order.

Answer (score 4):

[`Collections.reverse()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%3C?%3E%29) reverses any instance of [`List`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html). So yes, you can use `Collections.reverse()` on an [`ArrayList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html), or any instance of [`List`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html).

But anyway, here's how'd you write it by hand if you wanted:

```
static void reverse(List<?> list) {
  for (int i = 0, l = list.size() / 2, j = list.size() - 1; i < l; i++, j--) {
    Object tmp = list.get(i);
    list.set(i, list.get(j));
    list.set(j, tmp);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below generic method should reverse any type of List or ArrayList

```
public static <T> List<T> reverseList(List<T> listToReverse){
    List<T> reverseList = new ArrayList<>(listToReverse);
    Collections.reverse(reverseList);
    return reverseList;
}
```